# One more releasing and acquiring locks make performance worse unexpectedly

Tags: c++, multithreading, locking, race-condition

My program has 8 writing threads and one persistence thread. The following code is the core of the persistence thread

```
    std::string longLine;
    myMutex.lock();
    while (!myQueue.empty()) {
        std::string& head = myQueue.front();
        const int hSize = head.size();
        if(hSize < blockMaxSize)
            break;
        longLine += head;
        myQueue.pop_front();
    }
    myMutex.unlock();
    flushToFile(longLine);
```

The performance is acceptable (millions of writings finished in hundreds of milliseconds). I still hope to improve the code by avoiding string copying so that I change the code as followed:

```
    myMutex.lock();
    while (!myQueue.empty()) {
        const int hsize = myQueu.front().size();
        if(hsize < blockMaxSize)
            break;

        std::string head{std::move(myQueue.front())};
        myQueue.pop_front();
        myMutex.unlock();

        flushToFile(head);
        myMutex.lock();
    }
    myMutex.unlock();
```

It is surprising that the performance drops sharply to millions of writings finished in quite a few seconds. Debugging shows most of time was spent on waiting for the lock after flushing the file.
But I don't understand why. Any one could help?

Not understand more time spent on wait for the lock

Comment: The original implementation is fine. What triggers it to wake up? Do you use a condition variable?

Comment: Your second version is flushing small chunks to the file in each iteration of the loop, the first one is not.   If the file is on a device that is significantly slower than RAM (which is almost anything, including a hard drive, SSD, etc) that will tend to give a performance hit.   The first version uses `longLine` as a buffer - i.e. keeps data in memory until after the mutex is released, so any other thread waiting on that mutex will not be forced to wait until the file operations complete.

Comment: flushToFile() actually calls fwrite. Since the file is buffered, there should not be different in efficiency for both implementations. @Peter

Comment: @PanRuochen   You're missing the point, and assuming `fwrite()` will never flush the stream's buffer.   In reality, the buffer is finite, and - once criteria for flushing the buffer (e.g. it is filled) - contents of the buffer will be written to device during the `fwrite()` call.    The first sample of code has no potential of that while executing the loop.   The second code sample *does* have that potential.  All it takes is one operation of flushing the file buffer to device, and your second sample will slow down.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly faster. Do all your string concatenations inside the `flush` function. That way your string concatenation won't block the writer threads trying to append to the queue. This is possibly a micro-optimization.

While we're at it. Let's establish that `myQueue` is a vector and not a queue or list class. This will be faster since the only operations on the collection are an append or total erase.

```
std::string longLine;
std::vector<std::string> tempQueue;
myMutex.lock();
if (myQueue.size() >= blockMaxSize) {
    tempQueue = std::move(myQueue);
    myQueue = {};  // not sure if this is needed
}
myMutex.unlock();
flushToFileWithQueue(tempQueue);
```

Where `flushToFileWithQueue` is this:

```
void flushToFileWithQueue(std::vector<std::string>& queue) {
    string longLine;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < queue.size(); i++) {
        longline += queue[i];
    }
    queue.resize(0);  // faster than calling .pop() N times
    flushToFile(longLine);
}
```

You didn't show what wakes up the persistence thread.  If it's polling instead of using a proper condition variable, let me know and I'll show you how to use that.

Also make use of the `.reserve()` method on these instances of the vector collection such that all the queue has all the memory it needs to grow. Again, possibly a micro-optimization.

Comment: flushToFile just call fwrite to write the string to buffered file. There is not any string processing. The persistence thread is waken up by a semaphore which is triggered by any writer thread whose writing count exceeds a threshold.

Comment: Semaphore?  From which library? That could make a big difference if you're using an OS-level primitive for process synchronization vs a thread-synchronization library from pthreads or c++ std.